# Chrome and Firefox don't trigger actions in the same order

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a div which contains a checkbox. I have an observer on the checked attribute of this checkbox.

I couldn't stop the click propagation (name them, bubbles=false, preventDefault etc.). I tried everything.

So I came up with a solution : the checkbox observer fires before the action and changes the property.

For some goddamn reason, firefox decides to fire the action before the observer.

What should I do?

Comment: You should recreate the problem in a [jsBin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com) so we can also know what you are doing

Comment: I tried! but I got an error for some reason. Here it is anyway : http://emberjs.jsbin.com/cinimoreto/1/edit?html,js,console,output Not much use but I don't know why it isn't working, and the example probably won't reproduce the behavior. I'm stating my problem again : the observer fires after the action on the checkbox click. WHY? :( (in firefox and safari)